# Does a perfect crystal (in the sense of 3rd LOT) have to consist of a single isotope?

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose you have a monatomic "perfect crystal" at absolute zero. By the 3rd Law of Thermodynamics its entropy is zero. This makes sense to me in the sense of Boltzmann's entropy formula as there is only one microscopic configuration of this system (up to indistinguishable permutations of the atoms in the lattice). However, if the atoms were different isotopes it seems to me that these permutations would no longer be indistinguishable.For instance, if I were to pick any two atoms in the crystal that were different isotopes and interchange them the crystal "looks different" after the interchange. Would this not correspond to a different microstate and therefore a nonzero entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But this will only have a tiny influence on the properties of the crystal: the electron structure is far more important, the nuclei can be mostly treated as a fixed homogeneous background. The occasional different isotope will be a tiny disturbance to the mass distribution of that background.

OTOH, isotopic composition can be important near 0K because of intrinsic angular momentum aka spin, the classic example being helium-3 vs helium-4.